# Fabric JS setting fill on an image is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to set fill on an image using Fabric JS.

To demonstrate my problem I refer to the Kitchensink demo on `fabricjs.com`
http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink

On the image below I am trying to fill the image with a green color `RGB(69,242,81)` but when I set the color, nothing happens. Are there any workaround to this issue?

I have had a look at `floodFilling` but that is unfortunately too performance heavy for my use case.

Thanks!

[image]

## Possible Solution

I might have found a possible solution when playing around with this demo: `http://fabricjs.com/image-filters`

I select an object and choose the mode `tint` and increase the `alpha` to maximum (see image below)

[image]

And I get the desired result (see image below)
**Is there anything wrong with using this approach?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill isn't currently a recognized property for images. One reason for this is because drawing a solid color behind an image that isn't transparent causes that color to appear along the edges of an image. Since the image class inherits the default fill color of `rgb(0,0,0)` (black) from the Object class, that would mean that every image would have an outline like this, unless the fill color is manually changed to `transparent`.

[image: outline example]

If however you really want your images to respect the fill property, you can do this with a simple override to the `_renderFill` method of the Image class. Just be sure to set the fill of any images that don't need a background color to `transparent`.

```js
fabric.Image.prototype._renderFill = function(ctx) {
      var elementToDraw = this._element;
      if (!elementToDraw) {
        return;
      }
      var scaleX = this._filterScalingX, scaleY = this._filterScalingY,
          w = this.width, h = this.height, min = Math.min, max = Math.max,
          // crop values cannot be lesser than 0.
          cropX = max(this.cropX, 0), cropY = max(this.cropY, 0),
          elWidth = elementToDraw.naturalWidth || elementToDraw.width,
          elHeight = elementToDraw.naturalHeight || elementToDraw.height,
          sX = cropX * scaleX,
          sY = cropY * scaleY,
          // the width height cannot exceed element width/height, starting from the crop offset.
          sW = min(w * scaleX, elWidth - sX),
          sH = min(h * scaleY, elHeight - sY),
          x = -w / 2, y = -h / 2,
          maxDestW = min(w, elWidth / scaleX - cropX),
          maxDestH = min(h, elHeight / scaleY - cropY);
          
      //fill override start
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, sW, sH);
      ctx.fill();
      //fill override end
          
      elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw, sX, sY, sW, sH, x, y, maxDestW, maxDestH);
    };
```

[image: Fill example]

Comment: Thanks Melchiar is this the source code? Which parts should I overwrite this if I would like for fill to apply to images?

Comment: Also would providing a pattern work for this case? For example getting a pixel of the desired color and applying it as a pattern?

Comment: I changed the code in my `node_modules` with that you suggested, but that didn't seem to work for me. My image objects get the updated `fill` attribute, but I cannot notice any visual changes.

Comment: You should be able to drop this function right into your code without issue. I tested it by pasting it into the console in the kitchen since demo and it works fine. If you're having trouble please share a fiddle showing the issue.

Comment: Ah I see, I managed to get it to work, but is there a way to get the color on top of the image, at the moment it is only filling the transparent background of the image. I think it perhaps has to do something with the paint order?

Comment: Sure, just move the line of code with the drawImage call before the part where I added the fill override (indicated with comments). Not sure why you'd do that though.

Comment: I was playing around in the http://fabricjs.com/image-filters demo and I think I found an alternative solution to this problem, I will add it in the original question as an edit, I think I might have asked the question in an unclear way in the first place, what you do thing @melchiar?

Comment: Yes, the more information you can provide when writing the question the better. And yes, image filters are the way to go if you don't want to fill the transparent areas of the image.

Comment: I see, I previously didn't think that by only using a pure "fill" it was possible to achieve using only filters, but now in retrospect, that feels like a bad assumption.